# How to use trace() to edit C function call and setMethod call

Tags: c, r

Line 66th of [1] has a `.C` C function call to line 319-334 of [2] `cpmMLEStudent`.
`Ds` will be returned as `results`.

I would like to use `trace()` function to edit the C (or R setMethod code) so long that I can return `j`, `temp` and `E` to my `result`, ie:

`results$j`

`results$temp`

`results$E`

References:

1. [ChangePointModelStudent](https://github.com/cran/cpm/blob/master/R/ChangePointModelStudent.R)
2. [cpmMLE](https://github.com/cran/cpm/blob/master/src/cpmMLE.c#L319)

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to trace a .C call as that will be a compiled function.  Maybe there is a library that lets you recompile on the fly?  I don't know how it would get the original code though

Comment: If that is the case, first, I could comment out line 66. Second, rewrite `cpmMLEStudent` into R callable version. Then, the question now is: how to edit the setMethod to do so?

Comment: that sounds doable.  Is there a reason you don't want to just copy that method, edit it, and reevaluate?

Comment: how to edit that setMethod(f='getTestStatistics'...)? because typing command `trace(getTestStatistics, edit=TRUE)` gets me not the actual code in Rstudio  1.1.423

Comment: You cannot trace C code. You can modify it and recompile (by building the modified package).

Comment: you can lookup to methods definitions with `findMethod`/`s`, eg. something like`findMethods("getTestStatistics", classes="ChangePointModelStudent")`

Comment: Please don't use links to external (and thus volatile) sites. Extract a [mcve] and post that inline in your question.